# How do I get the terminal size in Julia?

Tags: julia

How do I get the terminal size in Julia?
Like the following code in Python:

```
import os
os.get_terminal_size()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `displaysize` function:

```
julia> displaysize(stdout)
(29, 134)
```